# How to make Payload of the verified_content.json file?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

everyone!
I want to modify the verified_content.json file in the _metadata folder of a Chrome extension. However, I am unsure how to properly modify the contents of this file. Can you please guide me on how to make the necessary modifications?

I tried to make a root_hash of the payload. But the result of my code is not correct.
Please give me the algorithm to make payload of the verified_content.json file.

Comment: You'll have to look in the [source code of Chromium](https://source.chromium.org/).